# E160E USB GSM Modem Continuously Dumps Data Into The Serial Port

Tags: python, gsm, at-command

I'm using a python script to send using Serial , a simple AT Command in this case "AT".
That normally returns OK , if everything is going well.

The problem is that after a few seconds the GSM Modem Will Dump the following.
RSSI:19 (yes i know this is the signal strength).

It also dumps :

```
BOOT:23243559,0,0,0,77
```

This is only occurs from time to time and it ONLY Happens in Linux it doesn't happen in Windows.

I tested this using the python script and putty in Linux and using Hyperterminal in Windows.
With the same serial config.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok  , So After A Couple Of Trial And Errors.
If you ever face this problem

Keep In Mind That E160 opens two (2) USB "ports" with the OS.
These two ports both can support AT Commands but one acts more like an "Status Monitor" Port while the other acts like a normal Port.

--- The Following Is Only Based On Experience ---

The Monitor port always has the highest number ( it's the second to register , you can take a look at dmesg ).

Also !

Its the port where CNMI Reports will come from so in short :

USB0 , Send At Commands no garbage ( you do all the stuff here )

USB1 , Monitor Port , Periodic Reports , Network Status And SMS Received Alerts are **ONLY** broadcasted here.

If you need help just respond :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, but probably it will help to somebody, the following command:

```
AT^CURC=0
```

disables the periodic status notifications